# Expected a type, but ‘i’ has kind ‘Nat’

Tags: haskell, types, type-kinds

I want to implement simple propositional logic with type-bounded size of the interpretation. But somhow I fail to convert type-level numbers to values using `natVal`. Sample code:

```
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

newtype PropositionalVariable (interpretationSize) = PropositionalVariable {
  getVariable :: Int
} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance KnownNat i => Enum (PropositionalVariable i) where
  fromEnum = getVariable
  toEnum e | e <= 0 = error "Variable must be positive integer"
           | (toInteger e) > (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy i)) = error "Variable index overflow"
           | otherwise = PropositionalVariable e
```

Gives me errors like:

```
• Expected a type, but ‘i’ has kind ‘Nat’
• In the first argument of ‘PropositionalVariable’, namely ‘i’
  In the first argument of ‘Enum’, namely ‘PropositionalVariable i’
  In the instance declaration for ‘Enum (PropositionalVariable i)’
```

What is the correct way to convert types level integers to values in this case?

Comment: I suspect it's inferring `interpretationSize :: *`. You need to turn on `PolyKinds` or give `interpretationSize` a kind annotation.

Comment: Thanks, adding PolyKinds helped. :-)

Comment: This should be marked as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn on `PolyKinds` extension or give `interpretationSize` a kind annotation.